# (Spring Boot, JpaRepository, Postgresql) Why is repository interface is not instanced during runtime?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

I'm making a small program using `Spring`, `Maven` and `Hibernate`. The current goal is to use `JpaRepository` to interact with a `Postgresql` database. However, when I try to call for it to list all entries in a table within the database, it spits out a `NullPointerException`. Online resources vary in their implementation, so it's been hard for me to understand what goes wrong.

My application can be summarized as follows:

**Javatest3Application.java** *(Outermost layer, handles communication)*

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@RestController
public class Javatest3Application {

    //---VARIABLES---
    private JavatestService service_handler = new JavatestService();
    
    //---PUBLIC---
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Javatest3Application.class, args);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<String> Login(@RequestBody Map<String, String> json_map) {
                
        //>>Read json_map for account_name and account_pwd
        
        //Ask Service layer to log user in
        Long session_id = this.service_handler.OpenSession(account_name, account_pwd);
        
        //>>Construct response, blah blah...

    }
}
```

**JavatestService.java** *(Middle layer, manages repository interaction)*

```
@Service
public class JavatestService {
    
    //---VARIABLES---
    @Autowired
    private JavatestRepository repo;
    
    //---PUBLIC---
    public JavatestService() {}
    
    public Long OpenSession(String in_name, String in_pwd) {
        
        //Call database for credentials
        List<JavatestUser> user_listings = this.repo.findAll(); //<- THIS FAILS
        
        //>>Go though list, blah blah...
    }
}
```

**JavatestRepository.java** *(Bottom layer, interface extention)*

```
@Repository
public interface JavatestRepository extends JpaRepository<JavatestUser, Long> {
    //List<JavatestUser> findAll(); <- Don't think I need to add this. I believe its already in JpaRepository
}
```

**JavatestUser.java** *(Bottommost layer, DTO class for database entry)*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "javatest_table", schema = "javatest_schema")
public class JavatestUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long account_id;
    
    private String account_name;
    private String account_pwd;
    
    public JavatestUser(){
        
    }
    
    //>>Getter and Setter functions, blah blah...

}
```

So, as far as I have understood it, we cannot instance objects of an interface. However, when using `Spring`, the program itself creates classes that implement the interface, and then hands such a derived class back to us via the `@Autowired` keyword.
Thus when we call the `findAll()` function, we use that derived class to fetch objects of the associated `@Entity` class.

From my research I've come to believe I might use the `@Service` keyword wrong, and that it perhaps should be a `@Controller`. However, as far as I can see, the are implementations of both alternatives, so my understanding of what differentiates them is somewhat lacking. Regardless of which I am using, the `@Autowired` doesn't seem to provide any `JavatestRepository`-derived object for me to call `findAll()` upon.

**EDITS**

- Added `@EnableJpaRepositories` in accordance with Eugene Botyanovsky's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing annotation, which enables all your repositories:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
```

It's similar to `@EnableAutoConfiguration` you used, but exactly for JPA repositories.

Comment: you do not _need_ this annotation, in a default set-up of spring-boot.

Comment: I've now added ``@EnableAutoConfiguration`` in my *Javatest3Application.java* file, but receive the same result.